# Access vba treeview (class MSComctlLib.TreeCtrl.2) how to add tooltip to each node

Tags: vba, ms-access, treeview, tooltip

My nodes work well in all respects, but I can't find a way to add tooltips to each node on MouseOver. How is this done?
I've tried setting this when adding node children but the property ToolTipText is not available.
My tool tips are stored in a table rsReqs!ToolTip and I'm looking for a method to set the tooltips when loading the Node.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Sample code used:

```
Private Sub addChildren(TV As Treeview, nodParent As Node, rsReqs As DAO.Recordset, lngParentID As Long)
Dim strFind As String
strFind = "ID_Parent=" & lngParentID
rsReqs.FindFirst strFind
Dim nodX As Node
Dim strBook As String
Do While Not rsReqs.NoMatch
'sets nodes with text from table rsReqs
    Set nodX = TV.Nodes.Add(nodParent, tvwChild, "<ID>" & rsReqs!PK_Req & "</ID>", rsReqs!mem_Req)
    Select Case rsReqs!ID_Type

        Case 1 'Menu

        Case 2 'Header
            nodX.Bold = True
            If nodX.Checked Then
                nodX.BackColor = vbGreen
            Else
                nodX.BackColor = RGB(244, 245, 247)  'vbWhite
            End If

        Case 3 'Function
            nodX.ForeColor = vbBlue 'RGB(0, 128, 0) 
            nodX.Bold = True

    End Select
    strBook = rsReqs.Bookmark
    addChildren TV, nodX, rsReqs, rsReqs!PK_Req
    rsReqs.Bookmark = strBook
rsReqs.FindNext strFind
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think you can.

Comment: could another tree control be used? Any suggestions?
Alternatively, how could a text box situated below the nodes be loaded with the tooltip text while hovering over a node?

Comment: This might work: https://microsoft.public.vb.controls.narkive.com/mPBTJ6uV/tooltip-text-in-treeview-control -- and there is https://jkp-ads.com/articles/treeview.asp (which I think has individual tooltips), but that would be a complete rewrite of your form, I guess.